# UnsatisfiedLinkError libreactnativejni.so App Bundle

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, android-app-bundle

I currently distribute an app over the Play Store. I use Android App Bundles for better download experience. Besides other libraries, I use `react-native`. Now I get multiple reportings from different users, that the app won't start. Looking into the error logs I received the error message looks like this:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libreactnativejni.so
       at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName + 738(SoLoader.java:738)
       at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName + 591(SoLoader.java:591)
       at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary + 529(SoLoader.java:529)
       at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary + 484(SoLoader.java:484)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit + 31(ReactBridge.java:31)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.<clinit> + 19(NativeMap.java:19)
       at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutorFactory.create + 25(JSCExecutorFactory.java:25)
       at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run + 944(ReactInstanceManager.java:944)
       at java.lang.Thread.run + 776(Thread.java:776)
```

The configuration in my `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a'
```

and if I unpack my app bundle, there is a lib folder containing an `armeabi-v7a` folder as well as an `arm64-v8a` folder. Inside those folder all the necessary library files are present, including `libreactnativejni.so` But there is one detail in all the error reports. My app uses ArCore and is therefore only compatible with specific devices. All the crashes I received come form devices, which don't support ArCore naturally, which means, that those devices are rooted but still downloaded the app from the Play Store. Do Android App Bundles not work with rooted devices or is there any other error I'm making?

Comment: Could you share what kind of devices you are seeing issues on? How did you figure that the devices are rooted and the app downloaded from Play?

Comment: We saw issues reported via email and via crashlytics. The devices affected I know for sure are Google Pixel 2XL, Google Pixel 1XL, and Samsung Galaxy On8. The Samsung phone was rooted for sure, I wrote with the tester using it. The reports we got from the Google phones indicated, that the phones were not rooted.
All apps were downloaded from Google Play because there is no other way to get our app. Furthermore, this was confirmed by the tester using the Samsung phone.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using App bundles you don't need to specify `ndk.abiFilters`, So remove it. Just add this in app level build.gradle file

```
bundle {
  abi {
     enableSplit = true
  }
```

}

Secondly you need React Native version higher than 59 to support App bundles.

Comment: You need to provide some context for this, like a file name or something.

Comment: Okay i have added now. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: This answer is wrong on several points: the App Bundle does not remove the need for the `ndk.abiFilters`, it may still be needed if some of the dependent SDKs compile native libraries for more ABIs. Also the `bundle` block is redundant since splitting by ABI is the default. React native version 59+ is correct though.